# If I can't improve a tag wiki edit, don't show me the button

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

Just now, I wanted to improve a [tag wiki excerpt edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/176). This is on an SE 2.0 site ([Unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)). Clicking on the `Improve` button brought me to [the tag wiki excerpt edit page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/8422/edit), which showed the 404 page not found content. I think I understand why — my reputation is in the 10k–20k range, so I can approve tag wiki edits but not make my own without supervision. But I shouldn't see the `Improve` button if I can't use it.

Comment: aha ... confirmed ... that is a bug, will fix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know when this changed, but this seems to have been fixed, as I don't see an `Improved` button on tag wiki suggested edits on Stack Overflow.