# Improving suggested edit tag wikis leads to a 404

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

Upon trying to improve a suggested tag wiki edit (no tag wiki had previously existed for that tag) here on MSO, I was brought to a 404.

Comment: This is caused by your being under 20k on Meta Stack Overflow. See the report at [If I can't improve a tag wiki edit, don't show me the button](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81229/if-i-cant-improve-a-tag-wiki-edit-dont-show-me-the-button). ♪

Comment: This may/ may not be related to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130304/404-when-submitting-an-edit-on-a-tag-wiki-from-the-revision-history

Answer (score 1):

I just experienced [a bug with the same visible behavior on U&L](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/951/page-not-found-when-improving-a-suggested-edit-to-a-tag-wiki-body): I improved a suggested edit to a tag wiki body which was creating the tag wiki, the suggested edit was approved while I was editing, and I was brought to a 404 page when I submitted my edit. This may or may not be the same bug given there have been changes around this part of the code. I have 20k on U&L.