# 404 when submitting an edit on a tag wiki from the revision history

Tags: bug, tag-wiki-excerpt, 404-not-found

For example, whilst on the [list of revisions for the](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/10312068/revisions) [unhandled-exception](/questions/tagged/unhandled-exception) tag...

1. Click the *edit* link of the latest version

   ```
   https://stackoverflow.com/posts/10312068/edit/9c489ccd-37de-4138-ae64-a1466df1b459
   ```
2. Make some changes... *la la la*
3. Click "Save Edit"

   ```
   https://stackoverflow.com/posts/10312068/edit-submit/9c489ccd-37de-4138-ae64-a1466df1b459
   ```
4. ... which is a 404

   [image]

Comment: It looks like editing this wiki results in...\*puts.sunglasses.on\*...an unhandled-exception. *YEEEAAAAHHHHHHH*

Comment: I've also seen this bug on the PHP tag wiki excerpt.