# Editing from the excerpt history results in "page not found"

Tags: bug, status-deferred, tag-wiki-excerpt

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Go to the excerpt history of a tag.
2. Click on edit.
3. Change the excerpt of the tag.
4. Save your edit and you'll see that "page not found" page.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130304/404-when-submitting-an-edit-on-a-tag-wiki-from-the-revision-history is a dupe of this.

Comment: @Matt: Tried to find one, came across some; I now see it somewhere hidden at the end of the related posts. My acceptance rate is higher, so they have probably chosen to answer mine first... j/k xD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I can reproduce this issue, we aren't going to fix it right now, due to time constraints.

The "edit tag wiki" code path is entirely separate from all other post types' edit path - so those edit links on a revisions page do not have all the logic needed to validate a tag wiki edit.

A refactor of our edit code is something that's near and dear to my heart and we will address this shortcoming then, but for now, I'm going to remove the edit and rollback links from tag wiki revisions pages for non-moderators.

The workaround is to use the "Edit Tag Wiki" button at the bottom of any tag wikis to improve either the excerpt or body.

Comment: Agreed, thanks for confirming and glad it's on the (undoubtfully long) list. Surely this isn't a major problem (hey, nobody really found this out for a long time; because the amount of 20+k people is limited and people don't usually get to those pages, or maybe it broke at some late point, who knows), just wanted to let you know. I agree that it's better to work on the more important features, and thanks for taking the links away... :)