# improve button in tag edition review

Tags: feature-request, tags, review, suggested-edits

[This tag excerpt edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2671236) has a simple grammatical error which I wanted to correct.

I have done it by going to the excerpt and suggesting another edit, but for such minor edits the `improve` button would be useful. The reviewer would then be able to correct the tag with 2 mouse clicks and in the same browser window.

When searching for this question on meta, I have found this: [If I can't improve a tag wiki edit, don't show me the button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81229/if-i-cant-improve-a-tag-wiki-edit-dont-show-me-the-button) -- it seems that this functionality was previously available (or was never available because of a bug). I think that it would be useful in some cases.

TL;DR I suggest adding the `improve` button for tag review also.

Comment: The functionality was never available. The button used to be shown, but pressing it didn't do anything useful, it only showed an error page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Full editing privileges for tag wikis](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) is a higher privilege level than [full editing privileges for questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit). You need 20k reputation for the former, and only 2k reputation for the latter.

Since you currently have ~5k reputation on Stack Overflow, you have full editing privileges and can click to "Improve" edits submitted on questions and answers.

But you have a way to go until 20k and full editing privileges for tag wikis, so there is no "Improve" button. The bug reports you found are talking about the "Improve" button being there for users like you, but generating an error when clicked because you do not have the appropriate privileges.

As for why this matters, the "Improve" button allows you to make instant changes to a post that are not filtered through the suggested edits queue and subjected to community approval. Therefore, it requires full editing privileges. It shows up once you reach 20k.

The typical workflow is to either "accept" or "reject" as appropriate, then go back later and make whatever improvements you would have made using the "Improve" button. It is an extra step, but it is required so we don't open up a backdoor to privileges you don't actually have.

Comment: So you are saying that the button will be there after I reach 20k?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. @dariusz

Comment: thanks. Should I delete the question or leave it for future reference?

Comment: @Dariusz You can't delete it now, it has an upvoted answer. But you should leave it anyway for reference. Don't delete questions just because you know the answer!

Comment: I don't delete questions unless an answer to them is already avaialble - and in this case, apparently, I haven't read the privileges page thoroughly, hence my question about deleting it.

Comment: The privileges pages don't say anything about improving edits, so you have to connect the dots. Or read this answer. :-) It's not a bad question.