# Ability to edit a suggested edit to a tag

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, review, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

I have recently been going through the review queue and come to a crossroads on what to do multiple times, here is my scenario.

[image]

This is an edit that I would like to approve because it has better content that what is currently available - I would also like to edit this so that the URL is in a hyperlink'd format - but I only have two options, Approve or Reject.

Now I can approve, and then find it, and edit it myself - but I think it would be easier if tag edits had buttons similar to the standard post edit where I could just improve the answer; no?

[image]

**Edit**

I found [this question from 13'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192253/improve-button-in-tag-edition-review?rq=1) which contains the answer to the above, which is that I will see an improve / edit button after 20k rep because I do not have enough privileges to outright edit the tag.

Could an edit button just change to body, and then re-add it to the review queue?

Comment: I realize that this _may_ belong on SE meta, if so, please migrate to avoid a duplicate post.

Comment: I realized that, and found the dup and linked to it. What would be the problem with it going back into the review queue if I think I can make it better?

Comment: That would be complex I think because something would have to be done to the original edit first - approve? But yours had to be reviewed. Reject? That's not fair...

Comment: I realize I am making this even more complex now... Could it not go through a process similar to what it would right now? I could approve this edit, it gets published, I edit in my suggestion, and it again goes through the review queue. If that were to get rejected, it could be rolled back to the previous version; in this it just would not be published until either one or the other was approved.

Comment: Yeeha! Review-stacking. How many levels would we need? And what if people approve of suggestion X, but not "putatively enhanced" suggestion X+1? Or disagree with your rejection, but want to enhance themselves? And all the other different combinations...

Comment: As an aside, that's a **tag excerpt**. Only plaintext admissible, the inline-code-formatting used doesn't work, it shouldn't contain any URLs, and anyway link-markdown is unavailable.

Comment: If you want to make further edits, you'll just have to wait until the current one is approved or rejected, or you have enough reputation to make edits yourself. We're not going to make the system more complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Edit" option in Q or A suggested edits is fine, because (generally) users need 2k rep to review and edit without approval.

For tags, users can review edit suggestions at 5k rep, but only edit without being reviewed at 20k rep, which is a large difference.

Your suggestion would essentially lower a 20k rep level privilege down to 5k rep, allowing users with 5k rep to edit tags without approval.

---

One way to resolve this is for the "Edit" from reviewers with less than 20k to reset the review back to as if it's a new review (no votes).

To be honest, this seems logical, and would arguably provide a means to ensure tags are edited to a decent standard through multiple reviewers re-editing and ensuring the edit is to a high standard.

But, it does add complications to what is currently a pretty simple system.

Also, [ᔕᖺᘎᕊ as pointed out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267317/ability-to-edit-a-suggested-edit-to-a-tag#comment867100_267317), what if the original edit was fine, and second user edited but made it bad. Then next editors have to re-edit, and so on.
This creates a loop where nothing is getting approved, with reviews being reset, and new edits to approve. However unlikely this problematic scenario may be, just introducing the "potential" is bad, to what is currently a fairly simple system which generally has a fast turn around.

In summary, I think the complexity introduced to manage such a feature greatly outweighs the benefits gained from a rare (ish) scenario which isn't in itself a large or frequent problem.