# Suggested edits - Tag wiki excerpt review description

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits, tag-wiki-excerpt

In the suggested edit review queue, for the tag wiki excerpt review, if I have reputation less than 20k, I will not see the [Improve button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/81229/312043).

But in the description box, the text message is not matching with that. If I didn't see the Improve button, can be the description text also corrected as per that?

> [image: Edit review]